# Incorrect dimensions in JPanel Image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

**Java Swing.** I have a `JPanel` called **panel_table** in which it loads clients into a `jTable`, which is contained by a `jScrollPane`.

In summary: `jPanel> jScrollPane> jTable`

- If there is data in the table, then we paint the table.
- If there is no data in the table, then we hide the `jTable` and paint
  an image in the `JPanel`.

My **problem** is that if there **is no data painted the image but with incorrect dimensions** to the .png file -said image-. Why? I dont get it.

**Code:**

```
public class Listado_clientes extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private TableRowSorter TRSFiltro;

    public class Imagen extends javax.swing.JPanel {
        public Imagen() {
            this.setSize(849, 377); //I put these measures because they are those of the JPanel "panel_tabla".
        }

        public void paint(Graphics grafico) {
            Dimension height = getSize();

            ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/error.png")); 
            grafico.drawImage(imagen.getImage(), 0, 0, height.width, height.height, null);

            setOpaque(false);
            super.paintComponent(grafico);
        }
    }

    public Listado_clientes() {
        initComponents();

        try {
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            tabla_clientes.setModel(modelo);

            //We make the query to the database... ... ...
            //We create columns and measures from the table... ... ...

            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
                for (int i=0; i<cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                }
                modelo.addRow(filas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }

        //If when loading the JFrame the database is empty ...
        int count = tabla_clientes.getModel().getRowCount();
        if(count==0){
            panel_top.setVisible(false);

            panel_tabla.setVisible(true);
            jScrollPane.setVisible(false); //hide JScrollPane and JTable

            Imagen Imagen = new Imagen();
            panel_tabla.add(Imagen);
            panel_tabla.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I show image when data exists in table:

[image]

**My image when there is NO data in the table -error here-:**

[image]

The image I have chosen to paint is as follows -measures: 1200x490:

https://www.solvetic.com/uploads/tutorials/monthly_05_2019/53b64448ef3386307fbbff957c37ae19.png

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: Your question has already been answered. In the future:1. Images should be posted in the forum 2. Post an [mre] to demonstrate your problem. 3. Don't do I/O in a painting method.

Comment: I think that i can't put a real-time example in this forum.

Comment: We are not interested in a real-time example. You were asked for an [mre].

Comment: If you want two components to share the same space on a JFrame then you can use a `CardLayout`. Only one component will be visible at a time. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples and example of an MRE.